# Community Promotion Ads - 2015

Tags: discussion, community-ads

The dawn of a new year, 2015, now approaches, or has already approached, either way it means that it is now time to reset our Community Promotion Ads!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- useful tools or resources for electronics work
- interesting articles or findings for the curious
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/4057).

Comment: Shouldn't there be a new question for this?

Answer (score 16):

[image: Laen's PCB order for hobbyists]

Answer (score 14):

[image: EEVBlog: An off-the-cuff video blog for electronics engineers, hobbyists, hackers and makers.]

Comment: Could you make this fit the new standard ad size please? It would really add a nice touch.

Answer (score 12):

[image: Q&A site for everything Arduino-related]

Comment: Is the ad of your design?

Comment: @NickAlexeev yes, that is, you mean if I made the graphic, right? I didn't build the PCB there.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I would nevertheless like to know what that board is.

Comment: @nitro2k01 after some google searching, it turns out to be a [40m/80m VFO by PY20HH](http://py2ohh.w2c.com.br/trx/vfo40-80/vfo40-80.htm).

Comment: For those of you who are wondering, PY2OHH granted permission to use this image here.

Comment: I personally don't understand the point of this ad. An Arduino is a controller, for which you need outside electronics to be useful. Thus, to me, I'd be interested in combining those two PCB's into something.

Comment: Unless what you're trying to say really is that Arduinoites are unable and unwilling to deal in anything outside their comfort zone of community-driven copy-paste designs and code, this ad is pretty stupid.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen: I think the ad's purpose is to show people that if they have an arduino-specific problem, there's a dedicated SE site for that. Not all arduino questions are in the scope of the electronics SE; to make a comparison:Programming is just applied computer science,computer science is just applied electrical engineering,EE is just applied physics.Hence,post all JavaScript questions on the physics SE. I think the message of this ad is clear and nice;if your question is about the arduino (and the arduino alone),post it over there.If it's about electronics attached,post it here.

Answer (score 12):

[image: Engineering Stack Exchange]

Comment: http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/174/community-ads-to-use-in-other-sites

Answer (score 11):

[See all questions with active bounties http://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/electronics.stackexchange.com/bounty.png](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured)

Comment: This is a dynamic picture. I am aware that this isn't 220x250 nor hosted on imgur, however, it is used [elsewhere](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/12383/125111) and when I flagged it, the mods told me it wasn't a problem. The ad is not of my design.

Answer (score 6):

[image: Support the FIRST Robotics proposal on Area51.SE!]

Answer (score 3):

[image: Check out the Area 51 Remote Sensing Proposal]

Answer (score 2):

[image: @StackElectronix]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Answer (score -3):

[image: SIMCOM Modules Firmware Resources]

Comment: "The image that you create must be 220 x 250 pixels"